# How correctly drag and drop GIF from Safari to our app

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari, drag-and-drop, gif

I need to correctly parse the GIF file dropped from Safari.
At Chrome or Opera it quite easy to do :

```
-(BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    if ([types containsObject:@"CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C20"]) // GIF format
    {
        NSData* gifData = [pb dataForType:@"CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C20"];
        NSString* someName = [self _sanitizeFileNameString:[[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pb] absoluteString]];
        NSString* tempStr = [[MSSettingsManager instance] tmpDir];
        NSString* randomFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld%ld%ld.gif",tempStr,random(),random(),random()];
        if (someName)
            randomFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ - %d.gif",tempStr,someName,rand()];
        [gifData writeToFile:randomFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

At safari, all incoming types in PasteBoard corrupts the GIF file.

NSFilesPromisePboardType - gives me nothing too.

```
if ([[pb types] containsObject:NSFilesPromisePboardType]){
    NSURL* newFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",[[MSSettingsManager instance] tmpDir]]];
    NSArray *filenames = [sender namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:newFilePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",filenames); // 0x000...
}
```

So, my questing is - how to get clear GIF file from PasteBoard or row file without any type.